# Is it fine to use "return Ok(await result)" in MVC/.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got this sample code I used in MVC/.Net Core Controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromQuery]string id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Person person= new Person { 
                Id = id,
                Name = "Test name"
            };
            return Ok(await Task.FromResult(person));
        }
```

The **await** is it fine to use inside Ok() ?

Comment: No - you have no async operation here. There's no need for `Task.FromResult` and hence no need for `await`. You're just allocating one more object and forcing the generation of an async state machine that does nothing

Comment: If you don't intend to call async methods, don't mark your own method as `async`. That won't make the method asynchronous automagically. HTTP requests are already served by separate threads. `async` tells the compiler the method is going to use `await` to await already asynchronous methods.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks. Actually I called that from client using RestSharp, like using .ExecuteAsync() method. So this is a good practice to remove that await inside the Ok(). I already used that puting await inside the Ok() but  no bad effect in our UAT deployment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for pointing out to remove the Task.FromResult

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah I understand how async/await works. The thing is if the await is just fine to use it inside Ok(await) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fine to use `await` when passing parameters to `Ok` (or any other method).

```
return Ok(await SomeMethodAsync());
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
var result = await SomeMethodAsync();
return Ok(result);
```

which is roughly equivalent to

```
var resultTask = SomeMethodAsync();
var result = await resultTask;
return Ok(result);
```

Comment: Thanks bro and stay safe.